# How to remove %20%20%20 in url? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

The following url:

```
<a href="{% url 'view' i.value %}" >VIEW DETAILS</a>
```

directs to:

```
http://localhost:8000/view/value%20%20%20
```

Instead it should direct to

```
http://localhost:8000/view/value
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove spaces from url then it should work.The escape character is %20 for space.